# Self join to create a new column with updated records

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a SQL query to get the start date for employees in a store. As seen in the first screenshot, employee number 5041 had the number A0EH but as the number got updated, it updated the start date for the employee as well. This effects the metric of total duration in the store.

[image: Table from SQL Query]

I am trying to get to the output below but haven't been able to figure out how to get this view.

[image: Desired Output]

This is the code I was trying but I am not getting the correct output.

```
    select
        esd.employee_number,
        (case when esd.old_employee_number is null then es.employee_number else es.old_employee_number end) as old_employee_number,
        esd.entity_id,
        esd.original_start_date
    from earliest_start_date as esd
    left join earliest_start_date as es
        on (es.employee_number = esd.old_employee_number)
```

How do I solve this on SQL?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  `SELECT version();`   That will determine what options are available.

Comment: this is on redshift

Comment: Please show the result of: `SELECT version();` unless this really isn't MySQL, in which case you should remove that tag from the question.

Comment: removed the tag

Answer (score 0):

Redshift reportedly supports recursion via `WITH clause`.  Here's an example:

MariaDB 10.5 has similar support. Test case is here:

[Fully working test case (via MariaDB 10.5) (**Updated**)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f72eb36873e3956e5107f702d80ce3c9)

Link to Amazon Redshift detail for `WITH clause` and window functions:

[Amazon Redshift - WITH clause](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html)

[Amazon redshift - Window functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html)

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (employee_number, original_no, entity_id, original_start_date, n) AS (
         SELECT employee_number, employee_number, entity_id, original_start_date, 1 FROM earliest_start_date WHERE old_employee_number IS NULL UNION ALL
         SELECT new_tbl.employee_number, cte.original_no, cte.entity_id, cte.original_start_date, n+1
           FROM earliest_start_date new_tbl
           JOIN cte
             ON cte.employee_number = new_tbl.old_employee_number
     )
   , xrows AS (
         SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id ORDER BY n DESC) AS rn
           FROM cte
     )
SELECT * FROM xrows WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+------+----+
| employee_number | original_no | entity_id | original_start_date | n    | rn |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+------+----+
| XXXX            | XXXX        |        88 | 2021-09-02          |    1 |  1 |
| 5041            | A0EH        |        96 | 2021-09-05          |    2 |  1 |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+------+----+
2 rows in set
```

Raw test data:

```
SELECT * FROM earliest_start_date;

+-----------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| employee_number | old_employee_number | entity_id | original_start_date |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 5041            | A0EH                |        96 | 2021-09-10          |
| A0EH            | NULL                |        96 | 2021-09-05          |
| XXXX            | NULL                |        88 | 2021-09-02          |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Note that the logic makes assumption about uniqueness of the employee_number and, in the current form, can't handle cases where the employee_number is reused by the same employee or used again with a different employee without adjusting prior data.  There may not be enough detail in the current structure to handle those cases.